# Swift 2 executing function after 3 seconds

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I am trying to simply execute a function after 3 seconds in swift 2. I have tried numerous things and none work. It is a sprite kit game in swift 2, Pleas tell me how to do this..

calling the function now looks like this
`self.adjustScore()`

**EDIT** Solved like this, thanks googe page 4

```
       let triggerTime = (Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 1)
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, triggerTime), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.adjustScore()
            })           
  })
```

Comment: You can user Perform Selector

Comment: Use `NSTimer` instead.

Comment: Don't edit your question to show the correct answer; you should answer your own question instead.

Answer (score 4):

Normally I would downvote the above answers, but the OP did not specify it is `SpriteKit` in the question title.  In `SpriteKit`, you do not want to use `NSTimers` or dispatch timers, because if you pause the scene, you do not pause these timers.  Instead, use a combination of `SKAction.waitForDuration` and `SKAction.runBlock` to achieve the desired effect

```
self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(3),SKAction.runBlock({[[unowned self] in self.adjustScore()})])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(3.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.adjustScore()
}
```